# How do I prevent a linked field and subform from editing my table in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Date Field and Subform linked by Date (pick a date, all records from that date show up in the subform.)

My problem is that when I pick a date, the most recently accessed record is CHANGED to that date...

I've tried setting Allow Edits on the subform to No but that didn't work. I've fiddled around with a few of the other options to no avail. Is this a simple solution to a simple problem? I have another form with a Date Field and Subform that works just fine, but that one has everything (edits, additions, deletions) set to No.

My ultimate goal is to display all records on a subform by date and delete the selected record.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply selecting a row should never perform an update. I'll bet your combobox or listbox (pick date) is bound to the date field! Unbind from the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field was a bound field, so the table was being edited even though I had Allow Edits set to Off.

I ended up unbinding the field and using queries to (1) display the appropriate records in the subform and (2) delete the selected record. I thought it'd be easier if I could use the bound field, but in the end I would've saved myself some time and headache if I just used queries to begin with.